# Limit on Number of Columns Pandas Will Print in Python

Tags: python, list, pandas

If I have a list of headers and I am using pandas:

```
[u'GAME_ID', u'TEAM_ID', u'TEAM_ABBREVIATION', u'TEAM_CITY', u'PLAYER_ID', u'PLAYER_NAME', u'START_POSITION', u'COMMENT', u'MIN', u'SPD', u'DIST', u'ORBC', u'DRBC', u'RBC', u'TCHS', u'SAST', u'FTAST', u'PASS', u'AST', u'CFGM', u'CFGA', u'CFG_PCT', u'UFGM', u'UFGA', u'UFG_PCT', u'FG_PCT', u'DFGM', u'DFGA', u'DFG_PCT']
```

Why do I get an output that is shortened

Like the following below:

```
PLAYER_NAME START_POSITION COMMENT    MIN   SPD   ...  CFGM  CFGA  \

  0  Billy Bob     G        37:42     4.12   5    ...    5    12
```

Why does pandas skip the other stats? Even though  my code states:

```
output= pd.DataFrame(data, columns=stts)
print output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done on purpose, more specifically through pandas' [Options and Settings](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html).

You can change it through `display.max_columns` which is set by default to `20`, as well as `display.max_colwidth`. Here's the full [default](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html#list-of-options) list of information.